# Finding a bijective holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I need to find a one-to-one holomorphic map from the open unit disc $D := \{z : |z|<1\}$ onto the open set $U := \mathbb{C} \setminus \{z : \Re (z) \leq 0, \Im(z) \leq 0\}$.

What I have done:  It suffices to find a bijective holomorphism from one half-plane onto $U$. But I am not being able to find such a map.

I thought that applying $z \mapsto e^z$ or $z \mapsto Log (z)$ somewhere will do the trick, but now it seems that I was wrong.

Can anybody please help ?? Any comment is welcome. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

A half-plane with the origin on its boundary subtends, at the origin, an angle of $\pi$; the region you want subtends an angle of $3\pi/2$.  So $z\mapsto z^{3/2}$ looks promising.

By the way, since $U$ is intended to be open, both of the $<$ symbols in its definition should be $\leq$.

Comment: @Andeas Blass Thanks, I have edited the definition of $U$. Can you please be more specific about the solution ? Apparently, $\Re (z^{3/2}) = e^{3log|z|/2} \cos (3 Arg (z)/2)$. Similarly we get $\Im(z^{3/2})$. But in that case, it can happen that $Re (z^{3/2}), \Im (z^{3/2}) \leq 0$. Please help

Comment: Apply $z\mapsto z^{3/2}$ to a well-chosen half-plane, namely the one consisting of complex numbers whose arguments are between $-\pi/3$ and $2\pi/3$.